# Azure API returning 204 No Content for Db-Calls with content

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-api-management

My setup: SQL Server database, .NET 5 Web API (with Angular 11 front-end) app.

Azure resources: Azure SQL Server, Azure SQL database, Web Apps for the front- and backend and API Management Service.

The issue: when I try to call the Azure SQL database from `myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/dbObject`, I get a "HTTP 204 No Content" error.

Diagnosis: when using localDb and localHost, everything works as expected.
When I connect the Azure database to my localHost, I can read & write from & to database.

When I call `myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/test`, I get two test strings returned, as intended.

But when I call `myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/dbObject/{id}`, a "204 No Content" is returned.

It should return the dbObject with the given id, as it does on localhost, but it's not happening

Db is up and running in the Cloud and so is the API.

What configuration could I be missing? And how could I find out myself?

What do I need the Gateway Url & Developer portal URL for in Azure?

And what Url should I use for database calls? `azurewebsites.net` where the app is hosted or `api-mngr.azure-api.net` where the app is managed?

In API Management Service, I've added an API and a version.
For testing I've added a get operation to api/test.
I've designed it to call `azurewebsites.net/api/test` (as is the web service url; front-end and back-end, without In- or Outbound processing), but when I Test that call I see an address `myapp-api-mngr.azure-api.net/api/test` as request URL, with a host also pointing to that baseUrl. Do I need to configure something between that web service and the `myapp-api-mngr.azure-api.net/` Url? How come that request URL is different from what I configured in Design?

Could not find similar questions here.

Thanks for input!

Comment: try to configure  Connection Resiliency. if you are using free azure sql db it's more important to have Connection resiliency. services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer           (
                  SQLDBConnection,
                  sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>                  {
     
                      sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 15, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                  }
                ));

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency

Comment: @NAS Thanks for the input! Configured as per your instructions, but did not change anything as to returned statuscode or response body! Would it return a 204 if did not get past failure on retry? I would expect more of an auth error in that case, no?

Comment: Wild guess -- any chance that you are testing with an `ID` value that perhaps EXISTS on your local system but does NOT EXIST in the Azure DB?

Comment: @DavidTansey Not in this case! I use the same seeder for both Dbs and those ID's are hardcoded. Also, I can get that object from CloudDb with LocalHost without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using the connectionstring from Properties in visual studio's SQL Server Object Explorer (right-click on the Azure SQL Server) instead of the one proposed by Azure upon creating the Db.

A bit silly, but there you have it.